# How do I use the matlib function plt.imshow(image) to display multiple images?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```py
def exiacc():
    global my_img, readimg , im, list_name, exis_img, tkimage
    print('Opening Existing Account...')
    topl = Toplevel()  
    readimg = './facedata/'
    list_img = os.listdir(readimg)
    row, col = 0, 0
    k = 0
    for fn in os.listdir(readimg):
        if fn.endswith('.jpg'):
            list_name.append(fn[:fn.index('_')])
            im = Image.open(os.path.join(readimg, fn))
            im2 = im.resize((200, 200), Image.LANCZOS)
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im2)
            exis_img = Label(topl, image=tkimage)
            exis_img.grid(row = row + 1, column = col + 1, padx=2, pady=2)
            exis_name = Label(topl, text = list_name[k] , font = ("consolas", 12, "bold"))
            exis_name.grid(row=row + 2, column = col + 1, padx=2, pady=2)
            col += 1
            k +=1
            if col == 5:
                row += 2
                col = 0
```

My results show that only the last processed image is shown effectively overwriting the other images.

Comment: You are not using `plt.imshow` so probably should change your title?

Comment: How to use 'plt.imshow' in my program.

Answer (score 0):

`plt.imshow` has a parameter `extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1]` that can position the image anywhere in a plot.  Annoying is that `imshow` forces the aspect ratio to be 'equal' (so distances in x and in y are forced to be the same number of pixels). Even more annoying is that `imshow` also forcefully sets the limits in x and in y.  To have more than one image, the limits need to be set explicitly (later than the call to `imshow`). If the 'equal' aspect ratio isn't wanted (it often *is* desired for images) `set_aspect('auto')` frees the aspect ratio again.

Here is an example, using different colormaps to get differently colored images.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmaps = ['Greys', 'Purples', 'Blues', 'Greens', 'Oranges', 'Reds',
         'YlOrBr', 'YlOrRd', 'OrRd', 'PuRd', 'RdPu', 'BuPu',
         'GnBu', 'PuBu', 'YlGnBu', 'PuBuGn', 'BuGn', 'YlGn']
img = ((np.arange(100) % 10) * np.arange(100)).reshape(10, 10)
cols = 4
for i, cmap in enumerate(cmaps):
    plt.imshow(img, extent=[i % cols, i % cols +1, i // cols, i // cols +1], cmap=cmap)
plt.xlim(0, cols)
plt.ylim(0, (len(cmaps) - 1) // cols + 1)
plt.gca().set_aspect('auto') # allow a free aspect ratio, to fully fit the plot figure
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward solution would be to use plt.subplots instead:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lst_cmaps = ['Greys', 'Purples', 'Blues', 'Greens', 'Oranges', 'Reds',
         'YlOrBr', 'YlOrRd', 'OrRd', 'PuRd', 'RdPu', 'BuPu',
         'GnBu', 'PuBu', 'YlGnBu', 'PuBuGn']

data = ((np.arange(100) % 10) * np.arange(100)).reshape(10, 10)

nxn = int(np.sqrt(len(lst_cmaps)))

plt, ax = plt.subplots(nxn, nxn)

for i, ax_ in enumerate(ax.flatten()):
    ax_.imshow(data, cmap=lst_cmaps[i])
```

This gives you an image like this:

[image]